# Let’s take a selfie!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> My suffix is innate
>   My prefix is on the coast
>   I capture your expressions
>   And remain the default for most

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you a

> PORTRAIT

*My suffix is innate*

> a "-trait" is innate

*My prefix is on the coast*

> a sea "port-" can only be found on coastlines

*I capture your expressions*

> a portrait ostensibly captures the face, as opposed to other photographs

*And remain the default for most*

> a smartphone's default camera mode is likely portrait mode